# Picasso not functioning consistently

Tags: android, picasso

I have a gridview which has lots of tiles - something like several hundreds. All the data is gathered from a webservice.

Each gridcell has two TextViews, a Button and one ImageView.

I was absolutely unable to load images using raw code written by me, the app would crash **every** single time giving OOM, so I decided to use Picasso. My asynctasks, by the way, are working perfectly.

I must say, the implementation is not only simpler, but my app hasnt crashed even once.

However, when Picasso will display images and when it won't seems to be completely random to me -

1. Sometimes, it would take ages to show the images in the cells currently in view (by ages I mean 30-40 secs).
2. At other instances, 2-3 images would load instantly and then no other will. I scroll down and see some images after a gap of 10-20 cells. Then another gap. Then some images.
3. I can see it is caching the images, but clearly there is some problem. It seems to "reload" the images when I scroll back to some place where I have already been.
4. Once I re-started the emulator and everything worked flawlessly. **Flawlessly.** Not so the next time. And not so the next time I re-started the emulator.

I won't go so far as to say Picasso is not dependable, for more chances are that I have messed up my memory management in some other way. However, if I have I am unable to point it out.

Here is my Adapter Class -

```
package com.tech4i.hujum;

// all imports

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DealsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    int width;
    public static List<Deals> deals_list;

    Deals deal;
    DealsViewHolder dvh;

    AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public DealsAdapter(Context context, List<Deals> objects) {

        mContext = context;
        deals_list = objects;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

   // ViewHolder
    class DealsViewHolder {

        ImageView pic;

        TextView details;
        TextView price;

        Button button;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        width = (int) ((MainActivity.width * 0.23 * mContext.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5);

        layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(width, (int) (width *      0.95));

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridcell_deals, parent,
                    false);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            dvh = new DealsViewHolder();

            dvh.details = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deal_details);
            dvh.price = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.deal_price);
            dvh.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deal_picture);

            dvh.button = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deal_shop_now_button);

            convertView.setTag(dvh);

        } else {

            dvh = (DealsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        deal = deals_list.get(position);

      Picasso.with(dvh.pic.getContext()).load(deal.getPhoto_link()).noFade()
            .into(dvh.pic);

        dvh.details.setText(deal.getDescription());

        dvh.price.setText(deal.getValue() + " /-");

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are asking a very broad question, there can be a lot of reasons for the same. I would suggest to add some code related to your question and narrow down the problem such that it is answerable.

Comment: I have added my adapter class code. I think the issue arises here only as this is where I load the images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that images you try to load are huge. So you may try to add resizing to Picasso methods chain:

```
Picasso.with(dvh.pic.getContext())
       .load(deal.getPhoto_link())
       .noFade()
       .resize(width, height) // <-- ImageView size in cell
       .into(dvh.pic);
```

It will reduce memory consumption. Also if your API allows you to obtain thumbnails instead of full version of images it will preferable to download them in grid view.